MapplsMap view taking screenshot
We are try to get screenshot Mappls MapView but return blank bitmap.we also attached screenshot which is return from
MapplsMap.snapshot(new MapplsMap.SnapshotReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onSnapshotReady(@NonNull Bitmap bitmap) {
                if (bitmap != null && !bitmap.isRecycled()) {
                    // Process the snapshot bitmap                    
                }
            }
        });

above method bitmap return black bitmap screen

